# How come Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI doesn't get any post data?

Tags: perl, http-post, catalyst, http-request

Whenever I `POST` something to a page with `Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI` I notice that my old CGI script doesn't get any `POST` data.. Data inside the body of the HTTP request. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, this was because I was using [`Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI) v0.35 and [`Catalyst::Controller::REST`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Controller::REST). This created a problem.. My configuration looked like this,

```
package MyApp::Controller::REST;
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller::REST' }
```

and

```
package MyApp::Controller::Root;
__PACKAGE__->config(namespace => '');
BEGIN { extends 'Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI' }
```

However, `Catalyst::Controller::REST` installs a [begin action](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Manual::Intro#Built-in-special-actions) [on line 298](https://metacpan.org/source/FREW/Catalyst-Action-REST-1.19/lib/Catalyst/Controller/REST.pm#L298)

```
sub begin : ActionClass('Deserialize') { }
```

And, that -- in my case -- was delegating to [Catalyst::Action::Deserialize::JSON](https://metacpan.org/source/FREW/Catalyst-Action-REST-1.19/lib/Catalyst/Action/Deserialize/JSON.pm) which is smart enough to `seek($body,0,0)` but too dumb and inconsiderate to do that for the next guy down the chain.... [Code below from here](https://metacpan.org/source/FREW/Catalyst-Action-REST-1.19/lib/Catalyst/Action/Deserialize/JSON.pm#L19)

```
if(openhandle $body) {
    seek($body, 0, 0); # in case something has already read from it
    while ( defined( my $line = <$body> ) ) {
        $rbody .= $line;
    }
}
```

And, to make matters even worse, the next guy down the chain in this example is `Catalyst::Controller::WrapCGI` which not just fails to clean up for the next guy, but fails to set it up for itself [(code from here)](https://metacpan.org/source/RKITOVER/Catalyst-Controller-WrapCGI-0.035/lib/Catalyst/Controller/WrapCGI.pm#L164),

```
if ($body) { # Slurp from body filehandle
  local $/; $body_content = <$body>;
}
```

That should look like (at the very least)

```
if ($body) { # Slurp from body filehandle
  local $/;
  seek($body,0,0);
  $body_content = <$body>;
}
```

That's why we can't have nice things... [I opened a bug in C:C:WrapCGI to get this resolved.](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=106569&results=71561ed0d850c6994b2ead49059b2158)